# Does $B^2 \leq A^2$ imply $\| A^{-1} B\| \leq 1$ for the operator norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Assume we have two $n \times n$ real symmetric matrices $ A^2 $ and $B^2$, such that it holds for some $0\leq\rho<1$
$$
0 < (1-\rho)B^2 \leq A^2 \leq (1+\rho)B^2,
$$
where "$\leq$" means positive semidefinite ordering. 
Is it true, that for the operator norm we have
$$
\| A^{-1} B\| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\rho}} \ ?
$$
As far as I understand, to obtain such bound we use only the inequality $(1-\rho)B^2\leq A^2$. Can we improve this bound knowing $A^2 \leq (1+\rho)B^2$?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** The answer is no. Conterexample: let $\rho = 0.99$,
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}, \ \text{and} \
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
20 & 0 \\
0 & 1.1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then the conditions are fulfilled, but 
$$
\| A^{-1} B\| = \frac{1.022}{\sqrt{1-\rho}}.
$$

Comment: This is true if $A$ and $B$ commute, but I'm not so sure about the general case.

Comment: Do you know any good source with a proof?

Comment: Yeah, if $A$ and $B$ does not commute, then it's not true